# Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Well, I'm trying to change a value of "variable" in Vue, but when I click on the button they throw a message in console:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "menuOpen"
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem...

My file.vue:

```
<template>
  <button v-on:click="changeValue()">ALTERAR</button>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'layout',
  props: [ 'menuOpen' ],
  methods: {
    changeValue: function () {
      this.menuOpen = !this.menuOpen
    }
  },
}

</script>
```

Any one can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The warning is pretty clear. In your `changeValue` method you are changing the value of the property, `menuOpen`. This will change the value internally to the component, but if the *parent* component has to re-render for any reason, then whatever the value is *inside* the component will be overwritten with the current state *outside* the component.

Typically you handle this by making a copy of the value for internal use.

```
export default {
  name: 'layout',
  props: [ 'menuOpen' ],
  data(){
      return {
          isOpen: this.menuOpen
      }
  },
  methods: {
    changeValue: function () {
      this.isOpen= !this.isOpen
    }
  },
}
```

If you need to communicate the change of the value back to the parent, then you should `$emit` the change.

```
changeValue: function () {
    this.isOpen= !this.isOpen
    this.$emit('menu-open', this.isOpen)
}
```

Comment: I thought I had done this, I saw many tutorials and had not gotten! Thanks dude.

Comment: Alternatively, since v2.3 you can use the `.sync` modifier: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier

Comment: if you use props and data, props will be initialized once and data is going to changing constantly. Is this ok?

Comment: I have this exact same issue but the difference is that I'm changing the value from the parent component... ???

Comment: LoL, using a getter instead of my prop in the child component, and a perfectly empty setter do the job without any console error.... : 
`// Getters & Setters
  private get localSelectedUsers(): Users[] {
    return this.selectedUsers;
  }

  private set localSelectedUsers(users: Users[]) {
  }`