# vuejs - computed is not working with props

Tags: vue.js

I'm using props to update my site content in the child component. This is basically working like this:

```
<child-component :updatedArray="updatedArray" />
```

then in the child component:

```
<template>
   {{updatedArray}}
   <div>{{computedArray}}</div>
</template>
<script>
   props: ['updatedArray'],
   ...
   computed: {
      computedArray() {
        if(this.updatedArray.item == "item one") {return "item one"}
       else {return "other item"}
       }
   }
</script>
```

Now this code should work in any case when I update `updatedArray` in my parent component. Then I see in my child component that my `{{updatedArray}}` is changing correctly, but my `computedArray` is not triggered and does not work.

Can I ask you why is this happening?
Does computed do not work with every props update?

How should I correct my code?

edit: not duplicate
I'm not mutating the prop, I rather only do a computed based on its value.

Comment: Help us out a little. The variable is named `updatedArray` but you are testing a key on it with `updatedArray.item`. What is `updatedArray`? An array or something else?

Comment: actually this is an object updatedArray: {item: "item1", item2: "item2"} etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Vue JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959824/instead-use-a-data-or-computed-property-based-on-the-props-value-vue-js)

Comment: @Sphinx This is not the case, I'm not mutating the prop, I rather only do a computed based on its value

Comment: why downvote? I really don't understand it. Computed should work on any change of the variable value, and it seems in my case that computed work only when child component rerender, while the variable value is changing correctly immediately

Comment: @Sphinx I can't do that, because I use other variables inside `updatedArray` object in the child component

Comment: Hah, you need to bind with `v-bind:updated-array="updatedArray"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your bind uses wrong name.

**As [Vue Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) describes:**

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret
> any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using
> in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased
> (hyphen-delimited) equivalents

So you need to convert **camelCase** to **kebab-case**.

like `v-bind:updated-array` instead of `v-bind:updatedArray`.

Below is one working demo using kebab-case. You can change it to camelCase, then you will find not working.

```js
Vue.component('child', {

  template: '<div><span style="background-color:green">{{ updatedArray }}</span><div style="background-color:red">{{computedArray}}</div></div>',
  props: ['updatedArray'],
  computed: {
    computedArray() {
      if(this.updatedArray.item.length > 0) {return this.updatedArray}
      else {return "other item"}
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {testArray: {
      'item': 'test',
      'prop1': 'a'
    }}
  },
  methods:{
    resetArray: function() {
      this.testArray['item'] += this.testArray['prop1'] + 'b'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button v-on:click="resetArray()">Click me</button>
<child v-bind:updated-array="testArray"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, this could be correct, but it's not working for me. I've got correct testArray values inside my child component. The problem is that my computed can't see it's changed :/ I mean It see but only when child component re-render

Comment: If bind correctly, it should not cause the issue you met. Can you change your codes to **kebab-case** then give a try?

Comment: I did it, with no success. But I can see that your code is clearly working as I would like it to work. The question is why my computed cannot see object value changes

Comment: It's really, really simple, what can be wrong?        `specPerson() {
          if (this.readyOffer.person == "physician"){
          return 'physician'      
          }else{
            return 'nurse'
          } 
        },`

Comment: {{readyOffer.person}} gives "physician"
{{specPerson}} gives "nurse" 
:/ xD

Comment: @gileneusz can you post out a full codes for your child component?

Comment: it's 600 lines of code, connected to parent, and with few childs :)

Comment: post data, props, computed, and mounted, don’t need method etc

Comment: where to post it?

Comment: Other components, parts, data, and computed works correctly, no errors or vue warns

Comment: @gileneusz Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168064/discussion-between-sphinx-and-gileneusz).