# Vuejs - Component not rendering to screen

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a vue app for budget tracking and I have a BudgetItems component that I want to render in the /budget route. All the other components and raw HTML render but this one component does not

This is the BudgetItems component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <BudgetItem v-for="item in Items" v-bind:key='item.id' v-bind:Item="item" />        
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import BudgetItem from './BudgetItem'
export default {
    name: 'BudgetItems',
    components: {
        BudgetItem,
    },
    props: [
        'Items'
    ]
}
</script>
```

And this is the BudgetItem component I used to render a single item:

```
<template>
    <div class="budgetitem">
        <h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
        <h1>{{item.value}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'BudgetItem',
    props: [
        'Item'
    ]
}
</script>
```

Last of all, this is the Budget page view:

```
<template>
  <div class="budget">
      <Nav />
      <h1>Budget</h1>
      <BudgetItems v-bind:Items="items" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Nav from "../components/Nav"
import BudgetItems from "../components/BudgetItems"
export default {
  name: 'Budget',
  components: {
    Nav,
    BudgetItems,
  },
  data(){
    return{
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          income: false,
          title: "Item 1",
          value: 200
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          income: true,
          title: "Item 2",
          value: 500
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          income: false,
          title: "Item 3",
          value: 10
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, when I look in the vue dev tools tab, the component appears, it just doesn't show on the screen

Comment: If it's there in the dev tools, I suspect it's there also in the DOM inspector? Could it be that you have CSS assigned to the "budgetitem" class that hides the items?

Comment: `<BudgetItems v-bind:Items="items" />`, props should use lower case. so change it to `v-bind:items`. and correct the declaration=Items of props inside BudgetItems .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vuejs - computed is not working with props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614574/vuejs-computed-is-not-working-with-props)

Comment: The cause of the problem is the case mismatch in `BudgetItem.vue`. Notice you use `item` in your template, but the prop is actually `Item` (uppercase). [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-data-binding-issue-f3l0h?file=/src/components/BudgetItem.vue:38-94)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `v-bind` declarations to lower case. Replace each instance of `Items` and `Item` with `items` and `item`.

Vue.JS doesn't like it if you capitalise props when using binding.

Please [read this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) for more explanation.

Essentially, browsers treat all attribute names as lowercase. As a result, it interprets "Items" as being "items".

Budget page view:

`<BudgetItems v-bind:items="items" />`

BudgetItems:

`<BudgetItem v-for="item in items" v-bind:key='item.id' v-bind:item="item"/>`

```
props: [
    'items'

]
```

BudgetItem:

```
props: [
    'item'
]
```

Once you make these changes, it works perfectly as seen here:

[image]

Comment: There's technically nothing wrong with using uppercase for `Items` and `Item` here. Case really only matters within in-DOM templates, but the OP is using an SFC, so that recommendation doesn't apply.