# Changing options per actions in the select section [Vue]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Javascript and Vue.
I have an annoying bug on my web.  Consider a navigation list which user has to choose one of the available options:

```
<div v-if="allOptions.length">
    <label>Please choose option:</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <v-select v-model="searchOptions">
            <v-option v-for="type in allOptions" :value="type">{{ type }}</v-option>
        </v-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are number of actions on the web. Let's call them: A,B,C. All of them has it own `allOptions` and I can jump between those actions.
User can jump to another action if he wants, but the number of 'allOptions' isn't reset, instead, it just puts the options of action1 to action2.

I'll try to explain it a little bit more with an example:
If I watch action A and move to action B - Now, for some reason, I can choose in the select section, both A's and B's option (should be only B's).

I tried to change `watch` by adding the following line:

```
$route (to, from) {
    if(to_action == "A") {
        this.allOptions = "option1,option2";
    }
    if(to_action == "B") {
        this.allOptions = "option3,option4";
    }
    if(to_action == "C") {
        this.allOptions = "option1,option5";
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.
```

After trying to figure out another way to solve this issue, I saw the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959824/instead-use-a-data-or-computed-property-based-on-the-props-value-vue-js). So I tried to add:

```
methods: {
    changeValue: function () {
    this.allOptions= allOptions
    }
},
```

But I get the same error as before.
How can I change `allOptions` per the action?
By the way, each action has its own consts file.

**Edit**

Another piece of code that should be helpful:

```
export default {
    router: router,
    props:['allOptions '],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you declare `allOptions` in component's data? Or you pass `allOptions` to component as a prop?

Comment: @ittus, Thanks for the replay. Please see my edit.

Comment: please provide the code that wraps the `$route (to, from) ....`